# null output of an 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

hello to @ll stackExchange community membres i hope youre all fine i have alittle question here about an 2D array

```
public static void fit(ArrayList <features> malade,ArrayList <features> learning) {    
      int e=malade.size();
      int i=learning.size();
      Double[][] multi = new Double[i][e];                 
      for (int cont = 0; cont >= i; cont++){
           for (int compt = 0; compt >= e; compt++){
               Double Plaglu = Double.parseDouble(learning.get(cont).plaglu)-Double.parseDouble(malade.get(compt).plaglu);
               Double press = Double.parseDouble( learning.get(cont).press)-Double.parseDouble(malade.get(compt).press);
               Double Tricep = Double.parseDouble(learning.get(cont).tricpe)-Double.parseDouble(malade.get(compt).tricpe);
               Double serins = Double.parseDouble(learning.get(cont).serins)-Double.parseDouble(malade.get(compt).serins);
               Double bmi = Double.parseDouble(learning.get(cont).bmi)-Double.parseDouble(malade.get(compt).bmi);
               Double fun = Double.parseDouble(learning.get(cont).fun)-Double.parseDouble(malade.get(compt).fun);
               Double pla = Plaglu*Plaglu;
               Double pres = press*press;
               Double tri = Tricep*Tricep;
               Double serin = serins*serins;
               Double bm = bmi*bmi;
               Double finc = fun*fun;  
               Double somme = pla+pres+tri+serin+bm+finc;
               Double sol = Math.sqrt(somme);
               multi[cont][compt] = sol;
               i--;
           }
           e--; 
      }     

      /*method number one*/    
      for (Double[] row : multi) {
          Arrays.fill(row, 0);
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row)); 
      }               

      /*method number two*/ 
      for(int r = 0; r < learning.size(); r++)   
      {
          for(int g = 0; g < malade.size(); g++)
          {
               System.out.println(multi[r][g]);
          }   
     }     
 }
```

i have tried 2 methods to print the result itch is multi and 
i got a `null`output or nothing the 2 `ArrayLists` are full
any help here

Comment: You'll find it easier to understand your code and find bugs in it, if you follow some [Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html). Currently, your code is terribly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this:

```
  for (int cont = 0; cont >= i; cont++){
    for (int compt = 0; compt >= e; compt++){
```

With using `<` instead fo `>=`:

```
  for (int cont = 0; cont < i; cont++){
       for (int compt = 0; compt < e; compt++){
```

Comment: nope i have tried this before it was bound exception

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the condition in the `for` loop is reversed:

```
for (int cont = 0; cont >= i; cont++){
   for (int compt = 0; compt >= e; compt++){
```

should be replaced by

```
for (int cont = 0; cont <= learning.size(); cont++){
   for (int compt = 0; compt <= malade.size(); compt++){
```

And no need for `i` and `e`.